# Plugin providing CMIS-compliant access to Liferay's Document Library?

Tags: document-management, cmis, webdav

[Liferay](http://www.liferay.com) enables content writers to manage a collection of documents via the Document Library portlet.

Documents in this space are [accessible via the WebDAV protocol](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Accessing+the+Document+Library+with+WebDAV).

Is there any plugin (or anything) to make this content also accessible via the [CMIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_Interoperability_Services) protocol?

[image: Liferay's Document Library]

Comment: FYI this question will be removed by [Roomba](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1116/903) in a few weeks if no comment, no upvote, no edit or no answer is added. (and I am not allowed to upvote)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I tried to improve it. This question is about a powerful but mostly unknown protocol, in server-side software that targets enterprise users, so no wonder it does not attract crowds...

Answer (score 0):

Liferay has a CMIS store:

[image: Liferay CMIS store]

which is deprecated:

> CMIS Store is not suitable for production use and is deprecated as of Liferay Portal CE 7.0 and Liferay DXP. Because it can have performance issues with large repositories, it’s recommended that you use one of the other configurations listed above, such as Advanced File System Store, to store your Documents and Media files. This deprecation does not affect the use of external repositories. You can still connect to external repositories using CMIS.

In addition, it supports AtomPub:

> From version 6.1, Liferay Portal comes with bundled Atom server and provides atom collections for several portal entities. Implementation is based on Apache Abdera, that is functionally-complete, high-performance implementation of the IETF Atom Syndication Format (RFC 4287) and Atom Publishing Protocol (RFC 5023) specifications.

**References**

- [Document Repository Configuration - Liferay 7.0 - Liferay Developer Network](https://dev.liferay.com/discover/deployment/-/knowledge_base/7-0/document-repository-configuration#using-the-cmis-store)
- [Portal Atom Collections - Wiki](https://web.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Portal+Atom+Collections)
- [Liferay Github Repo: CMISStoreTest.java](https://github.com/liferay/com-liferay-portal-store/blob/master/portal-store-cmis-test/src/testIntegration/java/com/liferay/portal/store/cmis/test/CMISStoreTest.java)
- [Liferay Github Repo: com-liferay-portal-store/ConfigurationAdminBundleActivator.java at master](https://github.com/liferay/com-liferay-portal-store/blob/master/portal-store-cmis-test/src/main/java/com/liferay/portal/store/cmis/test/activator/configuration/ConfigurationAdminBundleActivator.java)
- [CMIS Repository - Wiki](https://web.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/CMIS+Repository)
- [com-liferay-document-library/CMISRepository.java at master · liferay/com-liferay-document-library](https://github.com/liferay/com-liferay-document-library/blob/master/document-library-repository-cmis-impl/src/main/java/com/liferay/document/library/repository/cmis/internal/CMISRepository.java)
- [Document Library files atom collections - Wiki](https://web.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Document+Library+files+atom+collections)

Comment: It is the opposite of what I want. I want a plugin providing access to Liferay's Document Library, while this adapter provides access to external repositories.

Comment: [OwnCloud has a plugin](https://github.com/uzuzjmd/CMIS4Owncloud). Since WebDAV is the default, wouldn't you need both the plugin and the adapter?

Comment: OwnCloud provides access to its own content via CMIS. Similarly, I want Liferay to provide access to its own content.

Comment: The question is not about WebDAV. I have a CMIS client, and want to connect it to Liferay to consume Liferay content.

Comment: Looks like [Liferay is deprecating CMIS](https://dev.liferay.com/discover/deployment/-/knowledge_base/7-0/document-repository-configuration#using-the-cmis-store) store support.